# Shortening a huge list using an array value

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

As you can see below, I will end up having a huge list of code to accomplish an onblur and on focus scenario for a div and an input field. Is there a way to create a "list" and loop through it to accomplish what this code does line by line? Since I will have over 20 fields the page of code will be quite long.

```
document.getElementById('f1').onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById('f1').style.border = '1px solid #0033CC'
    document.getElementById('div_rssims_prefix').style.color = '#0033CC'    
}
document.getElementById('f1').onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById('f1').style.border = '1px solid #ABADB3'
    document.getElementById('div_rssims_prefix').style.color = ''   
}
document.getElementById('f2').onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById('f2').style.border = '1px solid #0033CC'
    document.getElementById('div_rssims_firstname').style.color = '#0033CC' 
}
document.getElementById('f2').onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById('f2').style.border = '1px solid #ABADB3'
    document.getElementById('div_rssims_firstname').style.color = ''    
}
document.getElementById('f3').onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById('f3').style.border = '1px solid #0033CC'
    document.getElementById('div_rssims_middlename').style.color = '#0033CC'    
}
document.getElementById('f3').onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById('f3').style.border = '1px solid #ABADB3'
    document.getElementById('div_rssims_middlename').style.color = ''   
}
```

An ideal list would be:

```
f1,div_rssims_prefix
f2,div_rssims_firstname
f3,div_rssims_middlename
```

ect.

Comment: Would you happen to have the corresponding html (and css) that goes with this snippet? I can a much better job if I'm not having to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript object to map the fields out, then loop through that object to assign the events.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jZCQV/1/

```
var objFocusPairs = {
    "f1": "div_rssims_prefix",
    "f2": "div_rssims_firstname",
    "f3": "div_rssims_middlename"
}

for (var curID in objFocusPairs) {
    document.getElementById(curID).onfocus = function(strID){
        return function(){focusStyle(strID)};
    }(curID);
    document.getElementById(curID).onblur = function(strID){
        return function(){blurStyle(strID)};
    }(curID);
}

function focusStyle(strID) {
    document.getElementById(strID).style.backgroundColor = 'aliceblue';
    document.getElementById(objFocusPairs[strID]).style.color = 'mediumblue';
}

function blurStyle(strID) {
    document.getElementById(strID).style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById(objFocusPairs[strID]).style.color = '';
}
```

Comment: Michael Geary's solution grabs the elements by ID before assigning the event handlers - this is probably the optimized way to handle that part. However, I believe doing a `split()` is probably poorer performance than mapping the pairs in an object.

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS selectors instead of Javascript.

[CSS Focus selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp).

Comment: How would you handle the color change on the other `div`?

Comment: @MichaelGeary what do you mean? The div's will switch colors automatically depending on them being selected or not.

Comment: @JohnSmith as much as it hurts to know that, it hurts more to know that you have to support IE7, specially when IE10 has been around for some time.

Comment: @Renan - the `div` elements don't receive focus and blur events when you click an `input` - the `input` elements receive those events. What selector would you use to make the `div` change color when the `input` focus changes?

Comment: OIC. Well, in that case, have a javascript function that receives an element as input and highlights or changes the color of its parent elements. Then use jQuery to retrieve all the inputs of the desired classed, and on the onFocus event, call that function. That way you achieve the OP's goal of coding everything just once and in one place when it comes to the JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the code to operate like it does now, using the exact DOM structure you have, you could do it like this:

```
setupFocusBlurList([
    'f1,div_rssims_prefix',
    'f2,div_rssims_firstname',
    'f3,div_rssims_middlename'
]);

function setupFocusBlurList( elements ) {
    for( var i = 0;  i < elements.length;  i++ ) {
        var ee = elements[i].split(),
            input = document.getElementById( ee[0] ),
            div = document.getElementById( ee[1] );
        setupFocusBlur( input, div );
    }
}

function setupFocusBlur( input, div ) {
    input.onfocus = function() {
        input.style.border = '1px solid #0033CC';
        div.style.color = '#0033CC';
    };
    input.onblur = function() {
        input.style.border = '1px solid #ABADB3';
        div.style.color = '';
    };
}
```

That said, there are other approaches that would make this a bit easier. Do you have control over the structure of the HTML code? And can you use jQuery? You could simplify this code quite a bit depending on how the HTML is structured - and even more if you can use jQuery.

Here's an example of what I mean. If you can write your HTML code something like this:

```
<div id="input-list">

    <div>
        <input id="f1" class="input-hilite">
        <div class="div-hilite" id="div_rssims_prefix"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="f2" class="input-hilite">
        <div class="div-hilite" id="div_rssims_firstname"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="f3" class="input-hilite">
        <div class="div-hilite" id="div_rssims_middlename"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

then you could use this jQuery code:

```
setupFocusBlurList( '#input-list' );

function setupFocusBlurList( wrapper ) {
    setupStyle( 'focus', '1px solid #0033CC', '#0033CC' );
    setupStyle( 'blur', '1px solid #ABADB3', '' );

    function setupStyle( event, inputBorder, divStyle ) {
        $(wrapper).on( event, '.input-hilite', function() {
            $(this).css( 'border', inputBorder )
                .parent().find('.div-hilite')
                    .css( 'color', divColor );
        });
    }
}
```

You could even make that code a bit simpler - with the specific HTML I listed above, you could use `.next()` where I wrote `.parent().find('.div-hilite')`. But this way it allows for more variation in the structure of those input+div blocks.

Or, if your HTML looks more like the example in [Xotic750's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470529/1202830):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div_rssims_prefix">Prefix
        <input id="f1" type="text" value="Prefix">
    </div>
    <div id="div_rssims_firstname">First Name
        <input id="f2" type="text" value="First Name">
    </div>
    <div id="div_rssims_middlename">Middle Name
        <input id="f3" type="text" value="Middle Name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could simply keep the `.parent()` and remove the `.find('.div-hilite')`, and use a different selector to get the `input` elements:

```
setupFocusBlurList( '#container' );

function setupFocusBlurList( wrapper ) {
    setupStyle( 'focus', '1px solid #0033CC', '#0033CC' );
    setupStyle( 'blur', '1px solid #ABADB3', '' );

    function setupStyle( event, inputBorder, divStyle ) {
        $(wrapper).on( event, 'input', function() {
            $(this).css( 'border', inputBorder )
                .parent().css( 'color', divColor );
        });
    }
}
```

Either way, it's worth noting that this code only sets up a grand total of two event handlers, compared with two *per input* with the plain JavaScript approach. That's because it uses jQuery's event delegation with the `.on()` method. So it's very efficient. Not that it matters with only 20 or so input fields, but if you had a large table it would make a big difference.

Comment: using an array of arrays would make the split() part unnecessary: `[['f1','div_rssims_prefix'],['f2','div_rssims_firstname'],['f3','div_rssims_middlename']]`

Comment: Agreed. It's a tradeoff: the array of arrays is more of a nuisance to write out, especially since it's something that is probably written by hand. The `split` adds a bit of complexity in one place in return for simplifying the list format. (And it's the format the OP asked about.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, do you really need to keep an array/list of ids within the script? This should work fine with IE7, but I don't have it to test with.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div_rssims_prefix">Prefix
        <input id="f1" type="text" value="Prefix"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="div_rssims_firstname">First Name
        <input id="f2" type="text" value="First Name"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="div_rssims_middlename">Middle Name
        <input id="f3" type="text" value="Middle Name"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    length1 = container.childNodes.length,
    i = 0,
    node1,
    length2,
    node2,
    j;

while (i < length1) {
    node1 = container.childNodes[i];
    if (node1 && node1.nodeType === 1 && /^div_rssims_\S+$/.test(node1.id)) {
        length2 = node1.childNodes.length;
        j = 0;
        while (j < length1) {
            node2 = node1.childNodes[j];
            if (node2 && node2.nodeType === 1 && /^f\d+$/.test(node2.id)) {
                node2.onfocus = function () {
                    this.style.border = 'solid 1px #0033CC';
                    this.parentNode.style.color = '#0033CC'
                }

                node2.onblur = function () {
                    this.style.border = 'solid 1px #ABADB3';
                    this.parentNode.style.color = ''
                }
            }

            j += 1;
        }
    }

    i += 1;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7AauS/)

Or perhaps a little more generic like this? I'm still basing this code on guessed HTML.

Javascript

```
function getElementsById(node, regex) {
    var nodeList = arguments[2] || [];

    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        if (regex.test(node.id)) {
            nodeList.push(node);
        }

        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            getElementsById(node, regex, nodeList);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    return nodeList;
}

var inputs = getElementsById(document.getElementById("container"), /^f\d+$/),
    length = inputs.length,
    i = 0,
    node;

while (i < length) {
    node = inputs[i];

    node.onfocus = function () {
        this.style.border = 'solid 1px #0033CC';
        this.parentNode.style.color = '#0033CC'
    }

    node.onblur = function () {
        this.style.border = 'solid 1px #ABADB3';
        this.parentNode.style.color = ''
    }

    i += 1;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7AauS/)

Or perhaps you have control over your markup and could do something like this instead

CSS

```
label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
input {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <label for="f1">Prefix</label>
    <input id="f1" type="text" value="Enter value"></input>
    <label for="f2">First Name</label>
    <input id="f2" type="text" value="Enter value"></input>
    <label for="f2">Middle Name</label>
    <input id="f3" type="text" value="Enter value"></input>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function getElementsById(node, regex) {
    var nodeList = arguments[2] || [];

    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        if (regex.test(node.id)) {
            nodeList.push(node);
        }

        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            getElementsById(node, regex, nodeList);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    return nodeList;
}

function getPreviousSibling(element) {
    var p = element;

    do {
        p = p.previousSibling;
    } while (p && p.nodeType !== 1);

    return p;
}

var inputs = getElementsById(document.getElementById("container"), /^f\d+$/),
    length = inputs.length,
    i = 0,
    node;

while (i < length) {
    node = inputs[i];

    node.onfocus = function () {
        if (this.value === "Enter value") {
            this.value = "";
        }

        this.style.border = 'solid 1px #0033CC';
        getPreviousSibling(this).style.color = '#0033CC'
    }

    node.onblur = function () {
        if (this.value === "") {
            this.value = "Enter value";
        }

        this.style.border = 'solid 1px #ABADB3';
        getPreviousSibling(this).style.color = ''
    }

    i += 1;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PvTS9/)